# Seems like pthread_create is overriding previous threads

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I'm trying to write an IRC type chat client which has clients that can connected to a server. I'm trying to get it to work locally atm (Using FIFOS instead of sockets).

I've run into the following issue which I can't seem to solve:

After accepting a new client connection, I want to create a new thread for that client (on the server) that'll handle inputs from that client.

To do this I have the following piece of code (the full code is at the bottom):

```
while(1) {
  .
  .
  .
  if (pthread_create(&thread, NULL, client_handler, &new_client) != 0)
    printf("Couldn't create a thread to listen to the client.... Not ok \n");
}
```

This works fine with 1 connected client.

The moment I try to connect another client it seems the previous thread that executed the method `client_handler` stopped running.
I know this because the server stops accepting input from that client, but the new thread works just fine (the one that handles the newly connected client).

I was wondering if my methodology was wrong or if I'm not using the pthread_create correctly.
Has anyone got any suggestions?

```
void server_listen() {
    Client new_client;
    ClientNode temp;
    buffint client_name_length;
    char client_name[CLIENT_NAME_SIZE];
    char fifo_in[FIFO_NAME_SIZE], fifo_out[FIFO_NAME_SIZE];
    buffint client_pid;
    char ack[4] = "/ack";
    char inuse[6] = "/inuse";
    pthread_t thread;
    buffint length;
    ClientNode it;
    buffint message_length;
    char message[MESSAGE_LENGTH];
    pthread_mutexattr_t attr; 

    while (1) {
        memset(client_name, 0, CLIENT_NAME_SIZE);
        client_name_length.data =0;
        if (read_helper(irc_server.server_fifo, client_name_length.buff,
                sizeof(int)) == -1)
            return; /* error */
        if (read_helper(irc_server.server_fifo, client_pid.buff, sizeof(int))
                == -1)
            return; /* error */
        if (read_helper(irc_server.server_fifo, client_name, client_name_length.data) == -1)
            return; /* error */

        pthread_mutexattr_init(&attr);
        pthread_mutexattr_settype(&attr,PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK_NP);
        pthread_mutex_init(&new_client.fifo_in_lock, &attr);

        printf("Reading from a new client, with name: %s\n", client_name);
        new_client.pid = client_pid.data;
        strncpy(new_client.name, client_name, client_name_length.data);
        new_client.name_length = client_name_length.data;
        sprintf(fifo_in, "fifo-%d-in", client_pid.data);
        sprintf(fifo_out, "fifo-%d-out", client_pid.data);
        new_client.fifo_in = open(fifo_in, O_WRONLY);
        if (new_client.fifo_in == -1)
            return; /* error */
        new_client.fifo_out = open(fifo_out, O_RDONLY);
        if (new_client.fifo_out == -1)
            return; /* error */

        read_lock();
        temp = client_exists_by_name(&irc_server.clients, client_name, client_name_length.data);
        read_unlock();

        if (temp != NULL) {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&new_client.fifo_in_lock);
            length.data = 6;
            if (write_helper(new_client.fifo_in, length.buff, sizeof(int))
                    == -1) {
                //TODO: What do we do if writing to the fifo_out failed?
                printf( "Writing to the fifo-out failed for some unknown reason \n");
                return;
            }
            if (write_helper(new_client.fifo_in, inuse, length.data) == -1) {
                //TODO: What do we do if writing to the fifo_out failed?
                printf( "Writing to the fifo-out failed for some unknown reason \n");
                return;
            }
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&new_client.fifo_in_lock);
            continue;
        }


        write_lock();
        insert_node(&irc_server.clients, new_client);
        write_unlock();

        length.data = 4;

        pthread_mutex_lock(&new_client.fifo_in_lock);
        if (write_helper(new_client.fifo_in, length.buff, sizeof(int)) == -1) {
            //TODO: What do we do if writing to the fifo_out failed?
            printf("Writing to the fifo-out failed for some unknown reason \n");
            return;
        }
        if (write_helper(new_client.fifo_in, ack, length.data) == -1) {
            //TODO: What do we do if writing to the fifo_out failed?
            printf("Writing to the fifo-out failed for some unknown reason \n");
            return;
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&new_client.fifo_in_lock);


        foreach(it, irc_server.clients){
            pthread_mutex_lock(&it->client.fifo_in_lock);   

            strncpy(message, new_client.name, new_client.name_length);
            strncat(message, " joined the chat", sizeof(" joined the chat"));
            message_length.data = sizeof(" joined the chat") + new_client.name_length;
            if (write_helper(it->client.fifo_in, message_length.buff, sizeof(int)) == -1) {
                //TODO: What do we do if writing to the fifo_out failed?
                printf("writing to the fifo_in a public message ERROR1 \n");
                return;
            }
            if (write_helper(it->client.fifo_in, message, message_length.data) == -1) {
                //TODO: What do we do if writing to the fifo_out failed?
                printf("writing to the fifo_in a public message ERROR2 \n");
                return;
            }
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&it->client.fifo_in_lock);
            memset(message, 0, MESSAGE_LENGTH);
            message_length.data = 0;
        }

        if (pthread_create(&thread, NULL, client_handler, &new_client) != 0)
            printf("Couldn't create a thread to listen to the client.... Not ok \n");

        if (pthread_create(&thread, NULL,client_handler1 ,&new_client ) != 0)
            printf("Couldn't create a thread to listen to the client.... Not ok \n");
        print_clients();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're sharing a single instance of new_client between all the threads in the server. A call to pthread_create() doesn't magically copy new_client. So every thread you create is using the same new_client. So when your master thread fills in values for a second client, the thread handling the first client tries to use those too.

Allocate a new new_client for each client, fill in the values and pass that into pthread_create(). You'll also need a per-client variable for the first parameter in pthread_create().

Other things - you're seemingly passing raw binary data between your client and server, things like string length integers. That kind of thing is going to cause you a whole pile of woe as soon as you have to start doing clients for different OSes. I strongly recommend you adopt a serialisation technology, preferably ASN.1 (not free but really robust) or Google Protocol Buffers (free but not as rich or robust).

Comment: I think allocating the client might be the issue!!! Thanks!
But why do I need to create a per-client variable for the pthread_create?

Comment: Well, it worked. You've just helped me solve a bug that I couldn't find for the past 8 hours or so. Thank you!

Comment: You're generally looking at other call pthread_join() at some point, so you will have to have remembered the pthread_t returned by each call to pthread_create().

Answer (score 1):

```
if (pthread_create(&thread, NULL,client_handler ,&new_client ) != 0)
...
if (pthread_create(&thread, NULL,client_handler1 ,&new_client ) != 0)
```

Why you are using same `pthread_t` variable every time? You can't use same thread variable. Prefer to use an array of `pthread_t` like this:

```
pthread_t thread[2];

if (pthread_create(&thread[0], NULL, client_handler, &new_client ) != 0)
...
if (pthread_create(&thread[1], NULL, client_handler1, &new_client ) != 0)
```

Comment: Isn't the ptrhead_t variable used only for the return value?

Comment: see the 'man pthread_create'

BTW correct this -as-
if (pthread_create(&thread[1], NULL,client_handler ,&new_client ) != 0)

if (pthread_create(&thread[2], NULL,client_handler1 ,&new_client ) != 0)